# How can I dynamically generate test cases with common test?

Tags: testing, erlang

With Common Test test suites, it looks like test cases must be 1:1 with atoms that correspond to top-level functions in the suite. Is this true?

In that case, how can I dynamically generate test cases?

In particular, I want to read a directory, and then, (in parallel) for each file in the directory, do stuff with the file and then compare against a snapshot.

I got the parallelization I wanted with rpc:pmap, but what I don't like is that the entire test case fails on the first bad assert. I want to see what happens with all the files, every time. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: No. I even tried using [Ghost Functions](https://medium.com/erlang-battleground/the-laziest-erlang-git-user-ever-ff69d86cf3c1?source=friends_link&sk=9e145468b8e57d2fb8fa30785a987b9b)

```
-module(my_test_SUITE).

-export [all/0].
-export [has_files/1].
-export ['$handle_undefined_function'/2].

all() -> [has_files | files() ].

has_files(_) ->
    case files() of
        [] -> ct:fail("No files in ~s", [element(2, file:get_cwd())]);
        _ -> ok
    end.

files() ->
    [to_atom(AsString) || AsString <- filelib:wildcard("../../lib/exercism/test/*.test")].

to_atom(AsString) ->
    list_to_atom(filename:basename(filename:rootname(AsString))).

'$handle_undefined_function'(Func, [_]) ->
    Func = file:consult(Func).
```

And… as soon as I add the undefined function handler, `rebar3 ct` start reporting…

```
All 0 tests passed.
```

Clearly common test is also using the fact that some functions are undefined to work. ‍♂️

Answer (score -1):

#### Data Directory

Each common test suite can have a "data" directory. This directory can contain anything you want. For example, a test suite `mytest_SUITE`, can have `mytest_SUITE_data/` "data" directory. The path to data directory can be obtained from the `Config` parameter in test cases.

```erlang
someTest(Config) ->
  DataDir = ?config(data_dir, Config),
  %% TODO: do something with DataDir
  ?assert(false). %% include eunit header file for this to work
```

#### Running tests in parallel

To run tests in parallel you need to use groups. Add a `group/0` function to the test suite

```erlang
groups() -> ListOfGroups.
```

Each member in `ListOfGroups` is a tuple, `{Name, Props, Members}`. `Name` is an atom, `Props` is list of properties for the groups, and `Members` is a list of test cases in the group. Setting `Props` to `[parallel|OtherProps]` will enable the test cases in the group to be executed in parallel.

#### Dynamic Test Cases

Checkout [cucumberl](https://github.com/membase/cucumberl) project.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but if I understand correctly it doesn't solve the problem I had. The return value of `groups()` is a list of atoms, where those atoms represent functions that are exported from my module. It doesn't sound like I can make that dynamic.

Comment: This adds more clarity for me. Are you trying to generate a list of test cases where each test case corresponds to one file in a directory? If so, this may be possible with eunit test suites and test generators